# Употребление слова "мистерия"

Tags: лексика, выбор-слов

В каких случаях слово  "мистерия" применяется в современных текстах?

Answer (score 1):

Из словаря:

**МИСТЕРИЯ**, -и; ж. [от греч. mystērion - таинство] 1. В Древней Греции, Древнем Риме и странах древнего Востока: таинство, система культовых обрядов, в которых могли участвовать только посвящённые. 2. В средние века в Западной Европе: религиозная драма на библейский сюжет.

Мне кажется, что современная мистерия — это театр, к котором реальные сюжеты имеют особый, метафизичный подтекст, где присутствует **таинство бытия**, которое неподвластно сознанию, но может быть выражено другими средствами.

[В ПОИСКАХ УТРАЧЕННОЙ МИСТЕРИИ | ptj.spb.ru](http://ptj.spb.ru/archive/83/theater-and-religion/vpoiskax-utrachennoj-misterii/)

"История русского театра с 1930-х годов до конца XX века основана на материалистической философии. ...  Но театр не может существовать **без метафизики, без религиозности в широком, «современном» смысле.** Мне кажется очень важным рассуждение Альберта Эйнштейна: «Самое прекрасное и глубокое переживание, выпадающее на долю человека, — это ощущение таинственности. Оно лежит в основе религии и всех наиболее глубоких тенденций в искусстве и науке...В этом смысле я религиозен».

Answer (score 0):

*Мистерия в переводе с греческого означает “погружение в тайну, таинство или священнодействие”.*

**Мистерия как жанр:**
 В настоящее время мистерии сохранились в Баварии, Швейцарии и Тироле, где представления устраиваются силами местных жителей. Отголоски мистерий можно обнаружить также в мексиканских религиозных праздниках. Мистерии, наиболее близкие к средневековым действам, уцелели в глухих и сравнительно отдаленных уголках Центральной Европы. Широко известна мистерия, представление которой с 1633 и по настоящее время повторяется в Обераммергау (Баварские Альпы) каждые десять лет.

**Мистерия в играх:**
Командная игра *"Мистерия убийств"*
*Мистерия* - текстовая ролевая онлайн игра в стиле фэнтези
Батутная арена *Мистерия*

**Мистерия в искусстве:**
*«Мистерия жизни*. Народный художник Илья Глазунов»
СМИ. Латвия. *Журнал "МИСТЕРИЯ"*
 Грандиозная *«Ночная мистерия»* [в Иерусалиме] раскрашивает окружающие руины, и оживают тысячелетия…
*МИСТЕРИЯ «ЗЕЛЕНОГО ЗМИЯ»* (статья в журнале "Вокруг света")
Выставка *"Мистерия воды"* в ДТ "У Вознесенского моста"
Эрмитаж отметит свой день рождения *«Мистерией света»* и бесплатным днем для посещения.
*АРТ-Проект Мистерия* - это содружество певцов - солистов Московских музыкальных театров, музыкантов, творческих коллективов.

Еще  **мистерия** встречается в названиях книг, фильмов, клубов, музыкальных групп; такое название имеет сеть магазинов по продаже разовой посуды, отель в Харькове, имидж-студия, питомник собак... Да что - где - как угодно!

[**Мистерия Сов**](http://eglareth.narod.ru/publ/stikhi/stihi0105/misterija_sov/2-1-0-159)
*Луна на ущербе. Поля холодны.

Никто не услышит шагов.

Оставь свои томные, скучные сны -

Сегодня **Мистерия Сов**!*

*...возможность очистить своё сердце, наполнить душу любовью, а тело силой! Растворитесь  **в мистерии чудес и волшебства**...*
***"Мистерия в разгаре"***, — так прокомментировала новость о запрете на ретрансляцию еще 14 российских телеканалов на Украине официальный представитель МИД РФ Мария Захарова.
*В Волгодонске «Феерия» отметила свое десятилетие **волшебной мистерией**.*
*Артемий Троицкий воодушевлен **«народной мистерией» Майдана** и не увидел там фашистов.*

Answer (score 0):

В современном русском языке слово "мистерия" употребляется в смысле

> впечатляющее, эффектное действие

Это переносный смысл, отсылающийся к античным греческим ритуалам
(например [Элевсинские мистерии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8)).

Разумеется, смысл, вкладываемый в это слово, может очень сильно разниться и нагружаться самым неожиданным содержанием (зависящим от уровня образования употребляющего).